# How to access elements with CEFSharp?

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am working with CEFSharp C# for the first time and im having a hard time figuring out how to make the browser do anything but browser.Load("");
I have been searching many websites for hours and hours and nobody seems to have an answer or have this problem. I am trying to access the website elements as if they were c# form controls... in a nutshell. I'm not supposed to ask broad questions... how would I do something like `browser.Click("/*elementName*/")`? Is Also, is there no way to do something like `browser.TextBox1.Text = "blah";`?

@Jim W

my code so far: updated 6/6/2018 4:29 pm

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace WebAppWorkAround
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();
        }
        List<string> classList = new List<string>();
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void InitializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
        public string extract;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string EvaluateJavaScriptResult;
            var frame = chromeBrowser.GetMainFrame();
            var task = frame.EvaluateScriptAsync("(function() { return document.getElementById('aaa').value; })();", null);

            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (!t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    var response = t.Result;
                    EvaluateJavaScriptResult = response.Success ? (response.Result ?? "null") : response.Message;
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());





        }
    }
}
```

errors:

Error   CS1061  'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   (line 61)

Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (line 62)

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#javascript-integration

Comment: I keep looking at this, but I cant read it... I just don't understand what anything in that code is doing, or how that lets me access the website elements. I seriously appreciate you trying to help though, Ive been trying to solve this problem for 7 hours...

Comment: You can access the DOM using JavaScript, that is the only supported method in CefSharp. You can easily write JavaScript to click a button.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/amaitland/9d354376960b0cd9305a for some more examples

Comment: Thank you! I'm starting to understand a little bit. But as an example, do you know how I'd have the program click the "ask question" button?

Comment: Execute JavaScript to perform the click. Use your favorite search engine if you need examples

Comment: As much as I have researched into this, I can only make CEF click things, following every piece of advice on getting the value for something, I still cant get evaluate scrip async to return any value... I have even copied peoples methods yet even the ones that are said to work, return no value... I don't know what to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's going to be as straightforward as calling

```
browser.TextBox1.Text = "blah";
```

As I understand it, CEFSharp is a way to execute Javascript from the C# wrapper.  It's not a C# version of the DOM (which is what it'd need to be).

So, from the Github wiki I would say you need to use this code

```
string EvaluateJavaScriptResult;
var frame = chromeBrowser.GetMainFrame();
var task = frame.EvaluateScriptAsync("(function() { return document.getElementById('<textBoxElementID>').value; })();", null);

task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (!t.IsFaulted)
    {
        var response = t.Result;
        EvaluateJavaScriptResult = response.Success ? (response.Result.ToString() ?? "null") : response.Message;
    }
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

and then `EvaluateJavaScriptResult` should have the text in the textbox.

Here's a complete working example, the designer just needs a Panel (panel1) and a Button (button1):

Run it, type something in the search box (in Wikipedia), and then hit the button, you should see a messagebox with the content of the search box

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChromium();
        }
        List<string> classList = new List<string>();
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void InitializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
        public string extract;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string EvaluateJavaScriptResult;
            var frame = chromeBrowser.GetMainFrame();
            var task = frame.EvaluateScriptAsync("(function() { return document.getElementById('searchInput').value; })();", null);

            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (!t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    var response = t.Result;
                    EvaluateJavaScriptResult = response.Success ? (response.Result.ToString() ?? "null") : response.Message;
                    MessageBox.Show(EvaluateJavaScriptResult);
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());





        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error on "frame" and line 8, it tells me that neither exist in the current context. I cant seem to fix the error. This does make a lot more sense though, do you have any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Does your `frame` come from code like `var frame = WebBrowser.GetMainFrame();`

Comment: ah, I actually don't have any code regarding frame, I don't have any knowledge on it.

Comment: Do you know the correct way to define frame in this context?

Comment: @SJ10 does the code in my comment work for you?  Where perhaps `WebBrowser` is `WebBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();`  You should show what code you have, it would make this easier.

Comment: adding the code var frame chromeBrowser.GetMainFrame(); gets rid of the error on "frame" but not line 8. I will update my question to include my code so far

Comment: "the name "EvaluateJavaScriptResult" does not exist in the current context" -p.s. sorry I was gone so long

Comment: @SJ10 sorry yes you have to declare that variable, see the updated code.

Comment: For some reason VS is saying there is an error on `Result` "Task does not contain a definition for '`Result`' and no extension method '`Result`' accepting a first argument of type 'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

and there is an error on `response.Success ? (response.Result ?? "null") : response.Message;`

the error is: cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists(are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @SJ10 any other errors, if you have several it can be more helpful to see them all at once, you could put them in the question.

Comment: These are the only two errors at this time. I'm not 100% sure what you mean, would you like me to post the lines that error in the question itself?

Comment: @SJ10 yes I mean just post the complete error info somewhere, the question is a good place because it's formatted.

Comment: `response.Result` should have been `response.Result.ToString()`, that's the second error, still not sure about the first but I'll try to setup a repro later.

Comment: @SJ10 Add `.ToString()` to `response.Result` (see my updated answer) and it actually fixes both of your errors.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! will this work with `getElementsByClassName` too?

Comment: @SJ10 No problem, yes it should do.

Comment: I feel like a nuisance for saying this, but I cant get this to work by class name

Comment: @SJ10 it's probably because `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, not a string.  Change `string EvaluateJavaScriptResult` to `object EvaluateJavaScriptResult`, put a break point on the `MessageBox.Show` line and then when it breaks, put your mouse over `EvaluateJavaScriptResult` and investigate what type it is (maybe string[]?).  If you're still stuck you should ask a fresh question.

Comment: strangely enough its just telling me a java error about how i'm missing a ")". I really appreciate your help, Ill write a new question at some point

Comment: @SJ10 then you've probably broken the brackets, put your caret on the opener `(` and check it has a closer (VS should highlight closing/opening brackets).

Comment: I will give that a look as soon as possible, sorry for the late reply, couldn't get to the internet

Comment: I just get the same error, idk, ill start a new question