# C# Cefsharp get value from element example?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, chromium, cefsharp

I have been trying to use CEF to read text from a web page for a few days now, in this time I have looked at every Stack Exchange, Github, (insert other websites here) page imaginable and none of what I have found has worked for me. I understand that I'm obviously doing something wrong, But can somebody please give me an example of a program that reads something from this page and displays it in a messageBox or something? It would be extremely helpful for me to work with it as a sort of template instead of trying to look at all the examples again. I could just edit the JS to find the element I'm looking for. Many thanks to anyone who can offer this

Comment: related (duplicate) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688705/how-to-access-elements-with-cefsharp

Comment: That is my post from before, I have tried the examples given to me but they don't return anything for me, even when copy and pasted and the only thing I change is the target element, (because that is necessary) but the return value is always nothing, I look up that error, hours later, still same error, even with every suggested fix. The only example that returned a value for me was the 1+1 example, which doesn't actually access the web page. That is why I want an example code that reads text off of this page, so i can run it, see it work, and understand it.

Comment: I know my page element location (ByClassName) is correct because it works when I use JS to click a button.

Comment: I cannot use examples like "GetElementByClassName('xyz')" because they don't actually find something on a webpage, xyz is just am example, and upon changing "xyz" to an actual class name, it still returns nothing

Comment: in any case, I don't think it is a good idea to quickly post several question which are essentially the same, here on Stack Overflow. It risks to be badly-received and/or moderated.

Comment: By the way, the other linked question has received an answer ;)

Comment: I will keep this in mind, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access elements with CEFSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688705/how-to-access-elements-with-cefsharp)